# Dynamics CRM on Premise App Server computer name as SQL Login

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

We have recently upgraded our Dynamics CRM system to new app and SQL servers. We noticed our app servers show as computer account logins (Domain\AppServerName$) on the corresponding SQL servers. Does anyone know why these logins are needed on the SQL server?

Thanks,
Bill

This is just an informational question. Everything is working on our CRM system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.